# Get value from mpfr (R) generated list

Tags: r, list

I m trying the following part of my code. where I got numbers between 0 and 1, that I need for the rest of my calculations.

```
V<-mpfr("ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff", base=16)

H <- rep(0, 10)

for (i in 1:10) {
   H[i]= mpfr(digest(i, algo="sha256", serialize=TRUE), base=16)/V
}
print(H)
```

so my problem here is that after printing the List H:

```
[[1]]
'mpfr1' 0.3755394259369469231611897454479156306810504715123336532380340752704582135787074

[[2]]
'mpfr1' 0.6551563805108653170634236534090611547455620826606370088028477863221605874721831
...
```

So I tried the following:

```
print(H[[1]][2])
Error in H[[1]][2] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

how do I access to only those floating numbers (without the 'mpfr1')? I tried several tricks and read the pdf of this Package but without success.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to get the numbers that I printed above.. the idea was to hash the i variable wich is an integer.. using digest(...,algo=sha256..) I got an hexadecimal number but as a character.. so I cant use it as number for my calculations.. and then if I try as.numeric, I will lose the precision. Any suggestions?

Comment: See my answer. You just needed to use `[[` for the list assignment. You can do all the arith methods noted in `?\`mpfr-class\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(Rmpfr)

V <- mpfr("ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff", base=16)

# idiomatic way to pre-allocate list storage
H <- vector("list", 10)
```

The issue is using `[` vs `[[`:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  H[[i]] = mpfr(digest::digest(i, algo="sha256", serialize=TRUE), base=16)/V
}
```

Print the whole thing:

```
print(H)
## [[1]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.3755394259369469231611897454479156306810504715123336532380340752704582135787074
## 
## [[2]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.6551563805108653170634236534090611547455620826606370088028477863221605874721831
## 
## [[3]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.3885949915720266863548135792781703111939691431200061007408307773606977937809833
## 
## [[4]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.3150499099587520139267833566690324328646190056708170872163816526136404907018551
## 
## [[5]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.6960615309583028424977971735890982334238399076523490261098745534587580595780822
## 
## [[6]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.5106268197476398863646910767785345221093749399244235093877311378854347607479013
## 
## [[7]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.6797735938098921024956339510265110382807465503448772685158966413891520889142766
## 
## [[8]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.7664394982397497402230927479011597236790782567007390733811624944306336973288917
## 
## [[9]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.2894251888739856297974876999320599099412274126754843872782469572239637764268605
## 
## [[10]]
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
## [1] 0.1950676091763967641866892764916813427538223237940125721449757977662242162599494
```

Work with individual elements:

```
as.numeric(H[[1]])
## [1] 0.3755394
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but is there a way to have more numbers after the comma? in your example we get only 7 numbers 0.3755394

Comment: You really need to read the help pages for this package. I fixed your main issue (using `[[` instead of `[`). If you want more help on actually using the pkg you should ask another question.